# Popover in twitter bootstrap doesnt work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, popover

There are already a bunch of threads about this topic which don't work for me at all.
Maybe I'm missing something really obvious. Here's my Code

My Includes (I use CakePHP)

```
echo $this->Html->script('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js');
echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min');
echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min');
```

My JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("[rel='popover']").popover({
        placement : 'top', // top, bottom, left or right
        title : 'This is my Title', 
        html: 'true', 
        content : '<div id="popOverBox">Your Text Here</div>'
        });
    });
</script>
```

My HTML:

```
<a title="" rel='popover'>Default Popover</a>
```

Comment: ... maybe the JQuery version. Assuming you're using the version of TB 2.3.2, it only work with version 1.4 of jQuery. I THINK, not sure. Worth trying.

Comment: Okay, got it. I put the javascript-Code in my default.ctp and now it works. Thanks.